# iMacro JAVASCRIPT WILDCARD VAR SIMPLE IF

Tags: javascript, if-statement, var, imacros

I am having issue with this simple if :)

```
iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0'+'\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=txt:*<SP>VLAN EXTRACT=txt');
var WELCOME = iimGetLastExtract(1)
alert(WELCOME);
if(WELCOME == ' Tunnel VLAN' || WELCOME == ' Service VLAN ')
{
alert('GOOD');
}
else
{
alert('BAD');
}
```

It is working for this one ' Service VLAN ' I am getting GOOD

```
<td style="outline: 1px solid blue;" class="data_nocolor_left" nowrap=""> Service VLAN </td>
```

It is not working for this one ' Tunnel VLAN' I am getting BAD

```
<td style="outline: 1px solid blue;" class="data_nocolor_left" nowrap="">&nbsp;Tunnel VLAN</td>
```

I already tried to play with spaces. I already copied extract from alert and it is still not working.

I can't remove   from that  Tunnel VLAN...

So there should be some way how to do it :)

I was thinking about wildcards but I haven't found anything.

Thanks to all for help.

Answer (score 0):

If that first character is causing you troubles, iry to ignore it in the comparison. For example :

```
if (WELCOME.substring(1) == 'Tunnel VLAN' || WELCOME == 'Service VLAN')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `if(WELCOME.match(/(Tunnel VLAN)|(Other LAN)/))` to find the text within the string instead then you can forget the spaces completely.